# Comparação de data no Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho uma lista de registros e nesta tabela eu tenho um campo `data_limite`:

```
$planos = $this->plano->whereIn('id',$planos_id)
                      ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
                      ->get();
print($planos);
```

Estou listando os dados do `array`, mais preciso pegar uma informação que seria a `data_limite` desta tabela e comparar com a data do dia?

```
$dateAtual = date("d/m/Y"); 
$dateCriacao = date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+".$dias_liberacao." days",strtotime($data)));

if($dateCriacao <= $dateAtual)
{
    return redirect()->route('listar-atividades')
                     ->with('status', 'A Atividade não esta disponivel parar edição!');;
}
```

Comment: Não entendi a sua duvida?

Comment: Use o carbon para comparação de datas: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison